# Mala performance Count Iqueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Mi problema es que al hacer el count de registros de un iqueryable demora muchísimo y es inconsistente. A veces demora 30 segundos para contar 11 registros y a veces cuenta 800000 registros en 10 segundos.

```
                    var FilteredItems = from ticketitem in db.Tickets
                                         where

                                         ticketitem.TransaccionID == ((TransaccionID == GET_ALL) ? ticketitem.TransaccionID : TransaccionID)
                                      //&& (ticketitem.KioskID == ATMID || ATMID == 0)
                                      && (listaATM.Count() == 0 || listaATM.Contains((int)ticketitem.KioskID))

                                      && (ticketitem.Transaccion.FechaHora >= FechaDesde || FechaDesde == null)
                                      && (ticketitem.Transaccion.FechaHora <= FechaHasta || FechaHasta == null)

                                      && (ticketitem.Transaccion.OT == NroOT || NroOT == 0)

                                      && (ticketitem.Numero == NroTicket || NroTicket == 0)

                                      && (ticketitem.Transaccion.Monto >= ImporteDesde || ImporteDesde == null)
                                      && (ticketitem.Transaccion.Monto <= ImporteHasta || ImporteHasta == null)

                                      && (listaEstado.Count() == 0 || listaEstado.Contains((int)ticketitem.Transaccion.EstadoTransaccionID))
                                      && (listaMedioDePago.Count() == 0 || listaMedioDePago.Contains((int)ticketitem.Transaccion.MedioPagoID))
                                      && ticketitem.Transaccion.TipoTransaccion.TipoTransaccionID == 3 //Ticket
                                      && db.TicketTarjetas.Where(tt => tt.TransaccionID == ticketitem.TransaccionID).Count() > 0 //Tiene que tener un ticket tarjeta

                                      //Filtro de comprobantes.
                                      && (ticketitem.NumeroComprobante == _NroComprobante || _NroComprobante == null)
                                      && (listaTipoComprobante.Count() == 0 || listaTipoComprobante.Contains((int)ticketitem.TipoComprobanteID))
                                      && (db.TicketTarjetas.Where(tt => tt.TransaccionID == ticketitem.TransaccionID).FirstOrDefault().NroCupon == NroCupon || NroCupon == 0)
                                      && (ticketitem.Token == NroToken || NroToken == null)
                                         select ticketitem.TicketID;

                //var arrayTicket = FilteredItems.ToArray();
                TotalRowCount = (FilteredItems).Count();
```

El count lo necesito únicamente para el total items del paginador de la vista.

Intente convertirlo a array y hacer el count desde la app pero demora mucho la conversion de iqueryable a int[].

Se me ocurrió hacer un stored procedure para el count únicamente pero no encontré la manera de pasarle al stored el iqueryable como parámetro.

Alguna idea de como hacer este count de la manera mas performante posible?

Desde ya gracias!

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Estas realizando filtros por muchos campos, seguramente muchso de esos no estan correctamente indexados en la db por eso demora segun como aplique el plan de ejecucion. 
Utiliza el `Sql Profile` para obtener el sql que ejecuta y poder analizar el plan de ejecucion y ver donde crear indices en los campos

Ademas si vas a realizar un count para que defines un select, pued usar directamente

```
db.Tickets.Count(ticketitem => ...);
```

donde puse los .. defines lo que ahora tienes en el where

Al usar el `SQL Server Profiler` obtendras la query que genera `entity framework` y podras analizarla, recomiendo apliques filtro por el nombre de la tabla

[SQL SERVER – Introduction to SQL Server 2008 Profiler – Complete](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-sql-server-2008-profiler-complete/)

[How To Filter DataBase Name And Login Username In SQL Server Profiler](http://4rapiddev.com/sql-server/how-to-filter-database-name-and-login-username-in-sql-server-profiler/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al obtener la query podras analizar la ejecucion y ver donde esta el problema de performance

[Análisis plan de Ejecución de query en Sql Server](https://rodrigopb.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/analisis-plan-de-ejecucion-de-query-en-sql-server/)

[Análisis de un plan de ejecución real](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/analyze-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El select lo utilizo para otra query que hay luego de hacer el count 

resultSetTicket = (from TicketItem in db.Tickets where
                             FilteredItems.Contains(TicketItem.TicketID)
                             select TicketItem).OrderByDescending(a => a.TicketID).Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

Tengo indices en cada "Foreing Key" por asi decirlo recientemente rebuildeados. Sobre sql profile no sabria que es ni como se utiliza pero me ayudaria sacar la SQL Query. Estuve buscando en google y no termino de entender como se utiliza tampoco.

Comment: Pero los filtros los aplicas sobre campos FK o otros que no solo con como por ejemplo del de fecha y aplicas filtros del estilo Contains() o sea demorar va a demorar la consulta mientras mas filtros apliques, la ejecucion no es magica. Quizas podrias ver de ir jugando con los filtros para detectar cual es el que genera la mayor demora

Comment: El Sql Profiler viene junto al Sql Server Management Studio. Edite la respuesta para poner un link que explica como utilizarlo